# Unmerging vertically in excel using VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have an excel sheet which contains merged data cells.
multiple classification is being done using the merged cells.

I want to unmerge tham and dump the raw data into anotehr sheet.
this is my task.
Please help me in this, i am fairly new to VBA.

the data is grouped and merged something like this

```
A  B  C
--------
x  x  x
      x
      x
   x  x
      x
      x
      x
   X  x
      x
      x
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Have you ever recorded a VBA Macro in Excel? You could record your actions and turn it into a repeatable function.

Comment: See here: http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/771-excel-fill-blank-cells-with-value-above.html

Comment: No need for VBA as far as I can see - simply select all relevant columns and unmerge. And if you need to fill the blanks, follow Tim's link!